# does anyone knows of any site that have a searchable index of unicode symbols

Tags: unicode, reference, symbols

Is there a site that would allow you to search for "arrow", for example, and provide all the Unicode symbols that match the keyword "arrow"?

This would be very handy :)

Ideally, it would also show the Unicode symbol rendered as an image for users without the requisite fonts who would otherwise see these chars as squares.

Comment: As well as the answers below, this page has helpful hints on finding unicode identifiers: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tools.scarfboy.com/unicode.html is awesome. It has an intelligent box that guesses what you mean, shows which encodings can correctly encode the character, and more!

(It does assume that the right fonts are installed, though... no server-side rendering.)

Comment: yeah pretty nice site ,but the problem is that some symbols are not displayed on my browser :( too bad there is no server side image generation.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) seems to be what you're looking for, and for example [this query](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=arrow&preview=entity) to it shows a table with 500+ lines (unfortunately some duplication of code points, as each code point is multiply found if it has multiple definitions containing the text "arrow").